# Why is this the probability distribution?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Given $X$ follows a Bernoulli distribution with parameter $p$, and $Y$ is some continuous random variable, why is the distribution of the product $Z = XY$ the following? Assuming that $X$ and $Y$ are independent:

$P(Z < z) = P(XY \le z) = P(XY \le z | Y = 0)P(Y = 0) + P(XY \le z | Y = 1)P(Y = 1) $

What allows this to be true? Is this an application of the Law of Total Probability?

$P(XY \le z ) = \sum P(XY \le z \ \cap \ Y) = \sum P(XY \le z  \ | \ Y)$

Comment: Looks like $P(XY\le z)=P(Y=0)+P(X\le z)P(Y=1)$ for $z\ge 0)$ and $P(XY\le z)=P(X\le z)P(Y=1)$ for $z\lt 0$.

Comment: I didn't try to answer your question because I didn't understand what point you are trying to make.

Comment: Do you mind explaining how you arrived at this distribution?

Comment: Straightforward.  When Y=$1$, XY=X and when Y=$0$, XY=$0$.  Assuming independence, the answer simply pops out.

Comment: Okay thank you.